# Access relationship of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have below three models:

- Stream
- FieldRoute
- Field

In my `Stream` model, I have:

```php
public function FieldRoutes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FieldRoute::class);
}
```

Then, in my FieldRoute model, I have:

```php
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
}
```

I am trying to access the `Field` model through `FieldRoute`, like so:

```php
$stream = Stream::find(1);

$routeFields = $stream->FieldRoutes()->fields;
```

However, above gives me the error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$fields

Am I even able to get the `fields`, that belongs to `FieldRoute`, by only having the `Stream` object?

Comment: What about has-many-through relationship?

Comment: `$stream->FieldRoutes()` could give you more than 1 result, so it will probably be under some collection. So, you better foreach the `$stream->FieldRoutes()` and access the dynamic property  `fields` on each element in iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna need some nested looping to handle nested relationships. But first, the error you're getting is due to a missing closure; you need to call `->get()` after the relationship name:

```
$routeFields = $stream->FieldRoutes()->get();
// Or, omit the ()
$routeFields = $stream->FieldRoutes;
```

Next, do some looping to get the fields:

```
foreach($routeFields AS $routeField){
  $fields = $routeField->fields()->get();
  // Or, again, omit the () (in fact, never use () in a loop)
  $fields = $routeField->fields;
}
```

Lastly, one more loop to access the properties of each `Field`:

```
foreach($fields AS $field){
  // Do whatever you want with $field...
}
```

Altogether, this would look like:

```
$stream = Stream::with(["FieldRoutes", "FieldRoutes.fields"])->find(1);

$routeFields = $stream->FieldRoutes;
foreach($routeFields AS $routeField){
  $fields = $routeField->fields;
  foreach($fields AS $field){
    // Do whatever with $field
  }
}
// Simplified
foreach($stream->FieldRoutes AS $routeField){
  foreach($routeField->fields AS $field){
    // Do whatever with $field
  }
}
```

Also, please fix your function name `FieldRoutes`, that should be `fieldRoutes` (function names are `camelCase`)

Note: I've used `::with()` to "Eager load" the relationships so you're not querying them while looping, as that's a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stream = Stream::with('FieldRoute.Field')->get();
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Add some context to the code you are showing to demonstrate how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try eager loading and plucking out the values.

```
$stream = Stream::with('FieldRoute.fields')->pluck('FieldRoute')->flatten()->pluck('fields')->flatten();
```